# Running a JAVA project with external jars folder

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to execute my `JAVA` app on a `Linux` OS where the necessary jars are located in a different folder. How can I execute my project using the external jars?

project location:

```
$ pwd
/root/MyApp/bin
$ ls
Deletion.class
```

jars location:

```
/opt/jars/*.jar
```

My failed execution:

```
$ java Deletion
... NoClassDefFoundError ...

$ java -cp "/opt/jars/*.jar" Deletion
Error: Could not find or load main class Deletion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the class path with `-cp ...`, you have to also specify the current working directory (as this is not part anymore):

```
java -cp ".:/opt/jars/*.jar" Deletion
```

Comment: Wow thanks.. I saw that in other post but ignored the dot, thought of it just as for jars import

Answer (score 0):

java -cp "location of jar file:." Deletion